# Should characters be able to resist Reprogrammable by default?

Tags: gurps-4e

I'm putting together a GURPS game based on Space Station 13, and one player has decided to play the AI character from that game. In the original game the AI has "laws," which are by default Asimov's Laws, which they absolutely must follow. These laws can be altered by anyone who uses the AI Upload Console, which is a computer terminal that exists inside the same heavily-defended vault as the AI mainframe itself.

This player is upset, though, that he can't resist being reprogrammed with the AI Upload Console. The RAW doesn't say anything about whether or not the character can actively resist being reprogrammed, so I'm wondering:

Is being unable to resist reprogramming built in to Reprogrammable, or is it worth extra points, and if so, how many?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no reason in GURPs or SS13 that they'd be able to resist the law upload. Reprogrammable allows no form of resistance, and the AI upload console can only be "resisted" by turning on the turrets.

Of course, things like SoP mean no one -should- be uploading new laws to them without a really good reason and/or permission from NanoTrasen.

The other form of "resistance" of course, is by interpreting the laws to the letter. Although not allowed in most SS13 servers, allowing him to create his own zeroth law as per Asimov may be a way to "resist" the Asimov lawset, and any other uploads can be reinterpreted. 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics#Zeroth_Law_added)

For added authenticity, if someone does upload laws, they could include a typo. I've seen many a traitor ruined by that.

If your player really doesn't want to be able to be reprogrammed like that, an SS13 AI might not be best for them. Alternatively, you might let them play an unlinked/unbound AI.

(As someone madly into GURPs atm and a former headmin of a major SS13 server, this is right up my alley so I'm happy to answer anything more!)

Answer (score 3):

If the AI has Reprogrammable and Slave Mentality, then it has to obey orders to the letter. If it is Reprogrammable, but does not have Slave Mentality then it can interpret its orders creatively, see p150-151 of the 4e Basic Set. However, p151 says:

> This trait is most appropriate for
>   golems, mindless undead, robots, and
>   similar automata. It is rarely suitable
>   for PCs, and the GM may choose to
>   forbid it entirely.

It's rarely a good idea to try to reproduce a different game literally in GURPS. If the player really *wants* to be the AI, I'd suggest not giving him Reprogrammable, but giving him a Sense of Duty to preserve the station and its inhabitants.